# When does the socket creation fails in C?

Tags: c, sockets, vxworks

I have to perform testing of socket related requirements for the software. As part of testing, I have to create a case for socket creation failure. My question is how do I make the C language socket() function return error value -1. The following are the lines of code to create the sockets in the software.

```
int socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

System configuration:

- OS: Windriver VxWorks
- Language: C

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Socket creation rarely fails except for invalid parameters or extremely low-resources conditions (but in those cases generally nothing works so attempting recovery is an impossible mission).

What can fail at runtime is for example a `listen` call because another process already is listening on the same port.

In windows socket creation most commonly fails because the the winsock initialization call has not been performed. This is IMO an horrible design bug in the API (so bad that makes me think it's an intentional attempt at prevent portability for no real reason).

Comment: Well invalid can be perfectly valid on other systems, autotools can set a flag to say if IPv6 is supported or not by the libc being used, so I guess there are versions not supporting that.

Answer (score 3):

The manual page says:

> ERRORS
>
> - `EACCES` Permission to create a socket of the specified type and/or protocol is denied.
> - `EAFNOSUPPORT` The implementation does not support the specified address family.
> - `EINVAL` Unknown protocol, or protocol family not available.
> - `EINVAL` Invalid flags in type.
> - `EMFILE` Process file table overflow.
> - `ENFILE` The system limit on the total number of open files has been reached.
> - `ENOBUFS` or `ENOMEM` Insufficient memory is available.  The socket cannot be created until sufficient resources are freed.
> - `EPROTONOSUPPORT` The protocol type or the specified protocol is not supported within this domain.
>
> Other errors may be generated by the underlying protocol modules.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in invalid values for the socket type.  Or open up so many file handles that it can't create a new one for the socket (the number this takes differs by OS and version).